# How to handle code-only answers in the VLQ queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

From time to time I encounter code-only answers (answers with just code, or with a heading similar to "Try this:" and code) in the low quality review queue. These answers usually answer the immedeate question of OP (they can copy/paste), but I think they are fairly useless to future visitors that have the same problem. Because the answer does not tell how they solved the problem, or what OP did wrong, a future visitor needs to understand the code from OP first, then has to understand the code from whoever answered the question, has to spot the differences and then apply those changes to their own code. I believe that to be hard for someone that couldn't fix their own code in the first place.

What should I do with such answers. I don't think deleting them is a good idea, because they do actually answer the question. The only other option I have in the Low Quality Queue is saying that it "looks good". Right now, I usually leave a comment and then click skip in the hope that they fix their answer. Editing the answer myself requires me to put too much effort into understanding the question and the answer fully. Should I handle it differently?

Comment: I would have though downvoting and hitting "Looks Good" would be the appropriate action - they answer the question but aren't useful to other users. Matches up pretty nicely with the downvote tooltip.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question

Comment: @JonK There are a lot of answers where the code can speak for itself. So I wouldn't agree that they ***automatically deserve a downvote***.

Comment: @user0000000 No, every answer is more clear if you sumarize in 1 or 2 lines what you changed to make it work. In any other case you need to read and understand the complete question before you can use the answer.

Comment: @user0000000 Generally I would hope that such answers wouldn't make it to the VLQ review queue in the first place, but as always with these, each answer needs to be judged on its own merit.

Comment: @user0000000 Information should not be in comments, but that would make it easier to edit. Just copy over the comment with some light editing.

Comment: One of the reasons I participate in the VLQ is to rescue perfectly good code-only answers from possible deletion. I've started to wrap some text around my code in answers to just to keep them out of the VLQ, but many times the text adds nothing to the code.