# Review audit dispute for a first post queue audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26765529) review audit is too vague to give a clear signal on (not) paying attention on the `First Post` queue.

My reasoning for the dispute are:

- while the answer is indeed not of the highest quality, being mostly code, the author did provide comments in the code to make it clear enough to understand for other users.
- I could agree Even with the "you are resurrecting an old thread" as an argument, but that kind of reasoning should be outside of the scope for a `First post` queue review.
- there are a few other answers under the same question that are "of a similar quality" to the audit answer and they are not deleted.

Comment: The audit is ok - reviewers should know without hesitation that the code-only answer is not "no action needed". There should at least be a comment, a downvote or a flag - take your pick. See this Q&A for [details on cody-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-an-explanation-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-ans/290233#2). Also, the post was on an old thread with a lot of answers already and thus was possibly an attempt at rep grab. Our jobs as reviewers is to be able to catch that even on autopilot

Comment: Thanks for the comment @OlegValter. Up until now i have  considered good in-code comments to be "passable" as an explanation of what the code does. I'll keep this feedback in mind in the future.

Comment: Don't forget that in First post review you are pretty much *expected* to look at the whole thread to weed out duplicate re-posts and all sorts of plagiarism in the same thread. You did not... so perfectly fair that you fail... and learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of unwritten rules here

1. People love to post "me too" answers on old questions. "I can solve this 8 year old question!" Well... yeah, but it was really solved 8 years ago. If you're going to answer, you need something *different*. The rule here is **be more suspicious of late answers**
2. The code block was posted without comment. Now, code-only answers can be OK, but it breaks another unwritten rule of **add something new to the answer pool**. In this case, the code block retreads what [this answer covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717614). You don't need domain knowledge to spot this, necessarily, just look for similarities.

When in doubt, click into the question and check.

As far as *audits* go, this isn't great because these rules aren't explained very well (if at all). You're not review banned, so there's nothing to be done here. I've taken some action to help ensure this answer isn't an audit anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Machavity! As you noted, I was not banned, so my main goal with this question was to better calibrate my own reviews moving onward. The key learnings from this are 1) be much more aware of the post age and treat old questions with greater care and 2) treat in-code comments as code, not explanation.